Sum Case when statement using Condition 1 minus Condition 2
I have a table that contains product totals as well as a pre-calculated grand total



Type
Agent
Rev




Product 1
Agent 1
100


Product 2
Agent 1
90


Product 3
Agent 1
200


GrandTotal
Agent 1
390



I can SUM where Type = Grand Total or I could SUM where type is IN (Product 1, Product 2, Product 3)
However, I have a need to SUM GrandTotal minus Product 3. SUM where type is IN (Product 1, Product 2 ) won't work for my purposes
, SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'GrandTotal'  THEN  ( Rev ) 
    - 
    WHEN Type = 'Product 3' THEN Rev
  ELSE 0 
  END
  ) as GT_ExcPrdct3

The answer I want to obtain is 190 -- 390-200

Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Excel?Go?Google? forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

@Adriaan it's a SQL question

What RDBMS?  SQL Server, DB2, Oracle, ....?

Do you store a pre-calculated value? Such too often leads to data inconsistency. Consider a view instead.

SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'GrandTotal' THEN Rev WHEN Type = 'Product 3' THEN - Rev END)

You need two separate conditional sums
SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'GrandTotal' THEN Rev END)
- 
SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Product 3' THEN Rev END)

I agree with others that it would be better to not to store the grand total and instead calculate it when needed.
You can use ROLLUP or GROUPING SETS for this. Exactly what should happen to the Agent column is not clear.
SELECT
  CASE WHEN GROUPING(t.Type) = 1 THEN 'Grand Total' ELSE t.Type END AS Type,
  t.Agent,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Type <> 'Product 3' THEN Rev END) AS Rev
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (t.Type, t.Agent),
    ()
);


Thanks both - @charlieface your first solution works here.  I wasn't able to exclude storing the grand total without a lot of re-work. There are lots of pre-aggregations going on that derive this and it isn't as simple as adding Products 1 + 2 so this works well.
Thank you!

Omit or ignore GrandTotal and calculate the grand total directly.
SELECT SUM(Rev)
FROM mytable
WHERE Type <> 'Product3';

or
SELECT SUM(Rev)
FROM mytable
WHERE Type NOT IN ('Product3', 'GrandTotal');

